# If statement condition is not satisfied, do not return error?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a variable `$cc`, this variable stores checkbox selections in this fashion:

251000-1,252000-2,252012-1 ... etc (Depending on how many choices)

I have successfully figured out how to store the data in multiple tables using a strpos if condition:

```
if (strpos($b,'251000') !== false) {
    $sql3="INSERT INTO engworkshops (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    echo 'true';
}

if (strpos($b,'252000') !== false) {
    $sql4="INSERT INTO engdrwnga (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    echo 'true';
}

if (strpos($b,'252012') !== false) {
    $sql5="INSERT INTO engdrwngb (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    echo 'true';
}

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql3)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql4)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql5)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
```

The problem lies here: The logic of this code only works if all three if conditions are satisfied, meaning that if my variable `$cc` contains 251000 and 252000 and 252012, it stores the data in each table with no problems whatsoever.

I tried

- nested if statements
- elseif statements

both didn't work

My guess is that the way I'm defining my insert statements and checking for errors in them if they are not executed is causing the problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: A [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) case.

Comment: Or `if (!strpos($b,'252012') || !strpos($b,'252012') || !strpos($b,'251000')) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check each of the conditions and set your `$sql` variables conditionally, but you use the `$sql` variables in the following queries whether they are set or not. So if any of the values you are looking for in the strpos checks are not found, your `$sql` variables will not be set when the queries try to use them, and your script will die.

In order for this approach to work, you need to move your queries inside your strpos ifs.

```
if (strpos($b,'251000') !== false) {
    $sql3="INSERT INTO engworkshops (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql3)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
    echo 'true';
}

if (strpos($b,'252000') !== false) {
    $sql4="INSERT INTO engdrwnga (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql4)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
    echo 'true';
}

if (strpos($b,'252012') !== false) {
    $sql5="INSERT INTO engdrwngb (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";
    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql5)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
    echo 'true';
}
```

Please note that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and this answer does not address that, only the logic issue.

Comment: I think that looks ok, yes.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to help. This is a separate issue, but I strongly suggest modifying your code to use prepared statements and binding your user submitted values rather than putting them directly into your SQL string.

Comment: Where can I start learning to build prepared statements ? Is it the same as PDO ?

Comment: Prepared statements are available in mysqli, but in my opinion they are easier to use with PDO. Check out the PHP documentation ([mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)). There are explanations and examples there that should help you get started.